# Responsive CSS image cross-fade

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I saw this demo: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ on how to cross-fade two images using CSS, and looking for a responsive solution to this, since that solution requires me to define the container's height and width.

This is the demo's code for those who don't want to click:

HTML:

```
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="/images/Turtle.jpg" />
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqaq77ec/

Thank you.

Comment: You can use percents and a container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://fiddle.jshell.net/gruqmh6j/

```
#cf {
position:relative;
height:400px;
width:400px;
max-width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
position:absolute;
max-width:100%;
left:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set a percentage width on the container and set `width:100%; height: auto;` on the images :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/nqaq77ec/2/)**

Comment: Thanks! Works - but I marked the newbie's answer as the chosen one so he can gather some credit :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
    height:100%;
  max-height:400px;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
    width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```